# thrust::sort_by_key system_error at memory location

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I am writing a program using cuda.
The problem is the following:
I have two arrays in *cu file:

```
particle* particles;
int* grid_ind;
```

Place on GPU is allocated for them:

```
void mallocCUDA(int particlesNumber) {
    cudaMalloc((void**)&particles, particlesNumber * sizeof(particle));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&grid_ind, particlesNumber * sizeof(int));
}
```

Both arrays are filled (confirmed). particles in its own init method and grid_ind :

```
__global__ void findParticleCell(particle* particles, int particlesNumber, int* grid_ind) {
    int index = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (index < particlesNumber) {
        int x, y, z;
        x = (int)(2.0f * (particles[index].predicted_p.x + 2));
        y = (int)(2.0f * (particles[index].predicted_p.y + 2));
        z = (int)(2.0f * (particles[index].predicted_p.z + 2));

        int grid_index = (BOX_X + 2) * 2 * (BOX_Y + 2) * 2 * z + y * 2 * (BOX_X + 2) + x;
        grid_ind[index] = grid_index;
    }
}
```

It is called in the following method:

```
void findNeighbors(int particlesNumber) {
    dim3 blocks = dim3((particlesNumber + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock);   // threadsPerBlock = 128 if that matters at all
    dim3 threads = dim3(threadsPerBlock);

    findParticleCell << <blocks, threads >> > (particles, particlesNumber, grid_ind);

    thrust::device_ptr<int> t_grid_ind = thrust::device_pointer_cast(grid_ind);
    thrust::device_ptr<particle> t_particles = thrust::device_pointer_cast(particles);

    thrust::sort_by_key(t_grid_ind, t_grid_ind + particlesNumber, t_particles);
}
```

The problem is that the sort method is causing

```
Microsoft C++ exception: thrust::system::system_error at memory location
```

for some reason. I have tried to resolve this for a couple of days now without any luck. Why does that exception occur?

Comment: Have you enabled Cuda backend when compiling?
`-DTHRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM=THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM_CUDA`

Comment: @dimaleks to be honest I have no idea where I should do that and what that means. To be clear, I tried sorting with a quick sort (without thrust) and everyting worked. So something about method calling or pointers is wrong may be?

Comment: CUDA is the default backend.  It's not necessary to explicitly enable it.  Instead, if you want help, you should add an MCVE as indicated by @m.s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried this code on the other PC and it worked without any problem.
Other people suggested that the problem on my PC might be in CUDA version / Video driver and whatever else.
Anyway, thats crazy...
I am sorry that I won't try to reinstall those things to check, since I found out that a custom sort method works not much longer than thrust::sort.